# Alternative for File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, file-handling

In some case the AppendToTextFile Method get's hangs and stops our DataFlushing logic. may i know what may cause it to hang any good alternative to over come this. this happens very rarely. what might cause this to hang.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public static void AppendToTextFile(string fileName, string textContent)
{
  if (textContent != null)
    {
      try
        {
         File.AppendAllText(fileName, textContent, Encoding.UTF8);
        }
      catch (Exception exception)
        {
          log.Error("Exception while writing to file " + fileName, exception);
                    throw exception;
         }
     }
     else
      {
        if (log.IsWarnEnabled) log.Warn("Attempting to write a null item");
       }
}
```

This how its implemented but AppendToTextFile and hangs and it doesnot release the lock

```
public static void QueueActivitiesToStore(string activities, int activitiesLength, ActivityAction action)
{  
    lock(obj)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUtil.AppendToTextFile(ProbeProperties.DataFlushProperties.DATASTORE_NAME, activities);
        }
        catch (IOException ioexception)
        {
            log.Error("Exception while inserting activities to store moving the file to .bak file.", ioexception);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it enter the exception? If yes what is the error message registered in the log file?

Comment: Do you synchronize access to the file?

Comment: no it is not writing any exception..

Comment: One of the reason you can see it is hanging is because of the Lock around the method you've added through MethodImplOptions.Synchronized. Trying removing and see if the issue reproduces.

Comment: If data is large, you may want to consider **asyc/await**

Comment: Do you have other `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` on `FileUtil` methods?

Comment: @Gururaj then i need to remove MethodImplOptions.Synchronized. really i dont how it makes difference and can you just explain me.

Comment: `File.AppendAllText(fileName, textContent, Encoding.UTF8)` is taking too much of time to exceute, how i can break the lock after some time.

Comment: Try to write to file in other ways like FileStream or something. I don't think it will be wise to terminate writing to file halfway as it may hold the lock and result into further exceptions

Comment: any more suggestions please...

Comment: Would running the `File.AppendAllText` in another thread in background work for you?